# Python - Replace Multiple Indices With One in For Loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to find a way to replace multiple indices with a single one.

Original list:

```
a[100] = "-277/480V RATED:"
a[101] = "Model L-N:"
a[102] = "B3 Ring Wave: 600"
a[103] = "C3 Combined Wave: 1300"
a[104] = "6kV-3Ka UL VPR: 1200"
a[105] = "Model L-G:"
a[106] = "B3 Ring Wave: 875"
a[107] = "C3 Combined Wave: 1300"
a[108] = "6kV-3Ka UL VPR: 1200"
a[109] = "Some other string"
```

The output I want is:

```
a[100] = "-277/480V RATED:"
a[101] = "Model L-N:\nB3 Ring Wave: 600\nC3 Combined Wave: 1300\n6kV-3Ka UL VPR: 1200"
a[102] = "Model L-G:\nB3 Ring Wave: 875\nC3 Combined Wave: 1300\n6kV-3Ka UL VPR: 1200"
a[103] = "Some other string"
```

I think I know how I'm going to concat everything. I'm going to a.startswith("B3 Ring Wave:) because that appears to be a constant and then join the indices above and below it with "\n" for new line.

Th issue is I don't know how I can replace the indices and if I can have this run in a for loop. My thought is that if I could replace them it would check a[101] which wouldn't match. It would move onto a[102] which would match so it would replace a[101-104]. It would then go into the for loop for a[102] which used to be a[105]. Is that correct?

```
original = ["Some Other Sting","-277/480V RATED:","Model L-N:","B3 Ring Wave: 600","C3 Combined Wave: 1300","6kV-3Ka UL VPR: 1200","Model L-G:","B3 Ring Wave: 875","C3 Combined Wave: 1300","6kV-3Ka UL VPR: 1200","Some other string"]

joinedList = []

for i, str in enumerate(original):
    if str.startswith("B3 Ring Wave:"):
        joinedList.append("\n".join(original[i - 1: i + 2]))
    else:
        "Do Nothing"
```

Comment: please provide a usable code to begin with, it is not possible to init a list like this

Comment: Sorry. This is what I came up with. I placed it in a new list but what I really want to do it replace multiple indices in a for loop. EDIT: I edited the main post.

Answer (score 0):

Removing elements from the list you're iterating over usually causes a lot of headaches. I strongly suggest creating a new list. Assuming that the sublist you want to replace always starts with "Model …" and contains three next lines, this could be done like this:

```
new_list = []
j = 0
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    if a[i].startswith('Model '):
         j=3                              # countdown from 3
    elif j>0:
         j -= 1
         if j==0:                         # countdown reached 0 - the final line
             conc = '\n'.join(a[i-3:i+1])  # concatenate 3 preceding lines and the current one
             new_list.append(conc)
    else:
         new_list.append(a[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

An option is to iterate through the list and alter one of the indices with your new value.  You could then record the indices you need to drop and do it afterwards.

Example

```
test_list = ["-277/480V RATED:",
 "Model L-N:",
 "B3 Ring Wave: 600",
 "C3 Combined Wave: 1300",
"6kV-3Ka UL VPR: 1200",
 "Model L-G:",
"B3 Ring Wave: 875",
"C3 Combined Wave: 1300",
 "6kV-3Ka UL VPR: 1200",
"Some other string"]


drop_inds = []
for item in test_list:
    if item.startswith("B3"):
        ind = test_list.index(item)
        change_string = '\n'.join(test_list[ind-1:ind+3])
        test_list[ind-1] = change_string
        for i in range(ind,ind+3):
            drop_inds.append(i)

final_list = [test_list[t] for t in range(len(test_list)) if t not in drop_inds]
print(final_list)

['-277/480V RATED:',
 'Model L-N:\nB3 Ring Wave: 600\nC3 Combined Wave: 1300\n6kV-3Ka UL VPR: 1200',
 'Model L-G:\nB3 Ring Wave: 875\nC3 Combined Wave: 1300\n6kV-3Ka UL VPR: 1200',
 'Some other string']
```

Comment: Making `drop_inds` a set instead of a list (and of course replacing `.append` with `.add`) would slightly improve efficiency of this code.